# 2011 Infiniti G37 - Throttle Response Issue

Tags: performance, throttle, infiniti, g37

When I step on gas in my G37 the throttle response is a bit lagged.  It has increased ever so slightly over the past 6 months.  Can someone explain what the cause of this might be and any preventative maintenance suggests I can employ to prevent it in the future?

There are no codes being set in the PCM and no check engine light.

I run the recommended fuel type of premium unleaded, follow all maintenance intervals and use all recommended fluids suggested by the manufacturer.

TIA

Comment: How many miles on your vehicle?

Comment: 27,000 miles on it

Comment: When was the last time you changed your air filter? I know you said "regular maintenance", but this is sometimes overlooked, even by the best of us. An air filter which is slowly becoming clogged would be starting to choke your engine and causing the issue you are suggesting. With a vehicle of that low mileage, I would be hard pressed say *your problems is <insert issue here>*. That's just broke-in for an Infinity.

Comment: about a month ago on the air filter

Comment: You might still run a scan on the O2 sensors to see how they are behaving. Also, give your MAF (if you have one) a dose of electronic cleaner, as well as cleaning out the upper intake tract. Another question ... how do you drive the car?? Short trips around town? You ever get it out on the highway for more than a 1/2 hour?

Comment: I work remotely in IT so mostly short trips but I get on the highway for longer than .5 hour two or three times a week.  When I do I ramp it up pretty hard quite a few times and have fun with it.  Safely though.  I'll follow your suggestions and report back.  TY

Comment: I strongly recommend you utilize a scan tool to probe what the car feels or you're flying blind. Specifically, we want to see the fuel trims for guidance on what the possible issue(s) could be. Your fuel trims could be bad but not bad enough to throw a CEL.

Comment: I do have a scan tool.  I just checked for codes though.  I've never gone to that next level.  I'll see if I can pull some data and share.  Can't be too hard.  I manage over a 1000 vmware servers so hopefully I can figure it out.  lol

Comment: Some people complained about this on the G35 as well, and said it was greatly improved by installing thicker gauge grounding wires.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some throttle lag is normal on electronic throttle equipped engines. Most drivers do not notice it. But those who do often ask why. The lag strategy is done so that the fuel control system can stay in closed loop control in an effort to keep the fuel mixture at stoichiometric during acceleration. Older systems designed for the less stringent emission limits in force at that time could be certified with cable actuated systems that do a poor job of fuel control on acceleration.

This model should be checked to see if service bulletin ITB12-027 applies. It corrects several transmission shift problems, some of which present as acceleration lag. It updates the software in the engine and transmission computers.

In my experience cleaning the throttle body has helped with poor idle but not acceleration lag.